# Logic for selecting random rewards

Tags: java, android, game-mechanics

I am making a RPG game and I am seeking a bit of information on how to grant players random rewards, such as game items, weapons, gold, etc... after defeating a monster, or a NPC of some kind. The items would be pre made and already existing. I am not sure on what is the best way to approach this kind of system. Any tips of advice will be appreciated on the matter.

Comment: Are you trying to generate random items, Diablo-style, or to simply select items out of pre-determined loot tables, like most other games?

Comment: my mistake forgot to mention that note, yes pre-determined items. I am not familiar with the term loot table also, is that an example of what I would need in my case? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I would have tried answering this myself, but I did a quick google and found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420046/Loot-Tables-Random-Maps-and-Monsters-Part-I which basically says everything you will ever need to know about random loot drop implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Well... you need to determine how your game's going to do it.

Thinking back on my days of playing Ocarina of Time, it always seemed to me that when I was low on health, turning some bushes into salad would reliably heal me up. If I was at full health, it would always drop rupees...

Divine intervention (aka game design) aside, under the hood it's all done with probabilities. Use the random number generator to make a probability function like `probability(percent)` that returns `true` `<percent>` of the time. Then it's just a matter of, when the enemy is vanquished, run its `drop` function or something similar.

```
void Drop()
{
    // Sometimes you want to drop one kind of item, but not the other kinds
    if( probability(20) ) {
         // 20% of the time.
         weaponDrop("common"); // Determines (using probabilities) which weapon to drop
    } else if( probability(20) ) {
         // 16% of the time
         itemDrop();
    } else {
         // 64% of the time
         goldDrop(10, 25); // Drop between 10 and 25 gold pieces
    }

    // Sometimes you want it to drop items regardless of what else you've dropped
    if(probability(.1)){
         weaponDrop("Super Cool Rare");
    }

    // Sometimes you want specific drops to always happen.
    dropDungeonMap();
}
```

I don't know what your game looks like in terms of the code structure, but the point is that it works on probabilities. Keep in mind that `if(20%)` implies that all the `else` branches *combined* have a probability of 80%.

Comment: Isn't better to calls only once to the random method?

Comment: I suppose. But you shouldn't think about performance until you need to. Besides, I don't call random more than once, I call `probability` more than once. You can have `probability` use a single global random number that gets updated on every iteration of the game loop.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will see what I can get from it :)